# Elaboration ordering file with tm package in R

Tags: r, frequency, text-mining, tm, file-organization

I created a script for the frequency of words in test documents (000_1.txt,000_2.txt,000_11.txt) in R. 
I want the file elaboration in order with numerical end (1,2,11).

The SO is Windows 7. The directory "E:\testR" contains the files.

This is the code

```
library("tm")

pathElaboration <- "E:/testR"
setwd(pathElaboration)
dirSource <- DirSource(pathElaboration, encoding =   "ISO-8859-2",pattern="*.txt")
vCorpusFiles <- VCorpus(dirSource, readerControl = list(language = "en"))
for (i in seq(from= 1, to=length(vCorpusFiles), by=1))
{
  dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(vCorpusFiles[i])
  vectorFrequencyWord <- as.matrix(dtm)
  print(vectorFrequencyWord)
}
```

But the result is

```
           Terms
Docs        file1
  000_1.txt     1
           Terms
Docs         wordinfile11
  000_11.txt            1
          Terms
Docs        wordinfile2
  000_2.txt           1
```

I would have the sequence 000_1.txt, 000_2.txt, 000_11.txt in elaboration

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a text sorting order, so this should work:

```
dtm <- dtm[order(Docs(dtm)), ]
```